# How does Kubernetes pull images

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a private registry and when I try to pull images I get a DNS lookup error. This is after following the steps provided in kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).

I just wanted to know what steps will kubernetes perform to pull the images from a container registry. Will the kubernetes master pull the images and deploy it in the nodes or is this also scheduled to the nodes to pull the required images

Comment: Are you using Kubernetes locally or in a cloud environment?

Comment: Is your registry correctly resolved from k8s? Try `nslookup <your registry>` from nodes

Comment: @daudnadeem The kubernetes is on Google and registry is private onprem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the master won't access your registry.
The nodes will pull the images when they need it (ie. when a pod that uses the images will be scheduled)

In your case, you must check that accessing the registry is possible from the nodes (you can try a manual `docker pull` for that)

If your registry needs some authentification, you will also have to add some credential in your namespaces secrets (but your "DNS lookup error" does tell that it is not your actual issue)